# no operator [] match these operands

Tags: opencv

I am adapting an old code which uses cvMat. I use the constructor from cvMat :

```
Mat A(B); // B is a cvMat
```

When I write `A[i][j]`, I get the error `no operator [] match these operands`.

Why? For information: `B` is a single channel float matrix (from a `MLData` object read from a csv file).

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) lists the `at` operator as being used to access a member.

```
A.at<int>(i,j); //Or whatever type you are storing.
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you should have a look at the most basic [opencv tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer)

so, if you have a 3channel, bgr image (the most common case), you will have to access it like:

```
Vec3b & pixel = A.at<Vec3b>(y,x); // we're in row,col world, here !
pixel = Vec3b(17,18,19);          // at() returns a reference, so you can *set* that, too.
```

the 1channel (grayscale) version would look like this:

```
uchar & pixel = A.at<uchar>(y,x);
```

since you mention float images:

```
float & pixel = A.at<float>(y,x);
```

you can't choose the type at will, you have to use, what's inside the Mat, so try to query A.type() before.

Comment: Felt this was clearer than the most basic opencv tutorial. Thanks.